# Is there an elegant solution for models that are very similair and do have a relation towards each other, but are not quite the same?

Tags: .net-core

I've recently started developing in .NET core.

When developing I encountered the situation that I have to make very similair models that aren't quite the same. For example, let's talk about a booking model:

**Frontend**: Here I need a model that gets posted as a JSON to my backend and gets deserliazed to a sort of FrontendBooking model.

**Backend**: I need to add Customer data to the booking, therefore I need to add fields like: CustomerName and CustomerAddress, based on their CustomerId. The backend needs to provide this data, I do not want the frontend to determine these fields. I combine these models to prepare it for an API call. To a model called RequestBooking.

**API**: I sent RequestBooking to an API and get a response with a similair object that has for example a Status and BookingId added, this was added to the model by the API. So I need to deserialize this to an object called: ResponseBooking.

**Database**: Finally I wish to store the object to a database, not all properties of the model are relevant however, therefore I create another model called: DatabaseBooking and store this to the databse.

When a property is added, removed or changed. Then I'll have to change it for each of these models.

Is there a design pattern or some other solution, so this is more manageable?

Also, what is best practise for naming these models? Naming them all Booking doesn't feel quite right and adding what they're used for doesn't feel quite right either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in general you will need different (although similar) models at least at these levels:

**Server**: here you can make use of Domain Driven Design. You will have an object Booking that is responsible for its logic and contain all properties and methods like e.g. *MarkAsCancelled*. You can use Entity Framework to use the same object in the database, which will correspond to a database table. EF allows you to mark some properties as not being saved in the DB. Also you can set up EF in the DbContext class and thus not use DB specific attributes in the class. So one object for DB and backend business logic.

**API**: obviously you cannot send your domain object to the API, e.g. REST. In the API you may want to combine properties of several domain objects or hide some properties. You will have to define a set of Data Transfer Objects (DTOs), e.g. BookingDto. How to convert your domain objects to DTOs? Solutions like AutoMapper may help. You just set up convertion rules once.

Now you can describe your API in e.g. Swagger. With Swagger Codegen you can than generate code for your server (.net) and client (e.g. JS).

In the end you will have to support the following:

- API definition (e.g. Swagger). Code for server DTOs and client
  objects is autogenerated. You modify API definition once, both sides
  get new objects.
- DDD Models that also are used for the Database. They
  may be faily independent from your DTOs. Mapping is handled for you
  semi-automatically by e.g. Automapper

All said is just a suggestion. All the layers and number of objects can and should be adapted to the specific needs of your project. E.g. you may want to use separate objects for the database if you are not using a relational mapper like EF or do not want to mix DB and logic.